# Copy Int to UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I have an `Int` which I want to copy to a pointer of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?`

I tried to cast it to Data and then copy it, but the copy function param is of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`

This is what I've tried:

```
var sizePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?
var numOfBytes = 100
var sizeData = Data(bytes: &(numOfBytes), count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
//What's now? How to copy it to the pointer?
//sizeData.copyBytes(to: size, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size) not working
```

Edit:

I have the following function, that gets a pointer. I need to copy the int to that address.

```
func f(pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?) {
    var numOfBytes = 100
    //copy numOfBytes  to the pointer's address
}
```

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to call a function which expects an argument of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`, then it's as simple as this:

```
func f(_ i: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
    print(i.pointee)
}

var x = Int32()
f(&x)
```

Comment: In that example lets say I want to copy x to the address pointed by i (where i is already malloced somewhere else).

Comment: So the equivalent of the C code `*i = x;`? In Swift, that would be `i.pointee = x`

Comment: Yes, but I want the value to be copied (since it's defined at a local function).

Comment: Roee84 Ints are structs, which are value types. They're always copied when assigned

Comment: Well, it was just an example. I want to *copy* Data to the pointer's address, but thank you and sorry for all the mess ;)

Comment: Well then ask a question that asks about copying data.